# How to check if a directory exists in puppet

Tags: puppet

Trying to create an autostart directory on a rpi using puppet. It is supposed to `mkdir` only if the location doesn't exist.

Here is the current code:

```
exec { "mkdir_autostart":
command => "mkdir /home/pi/.config/autostart",
unless => "[ -d /home/pi/.config/autostart ]",
path    => "/usr/local/bin/:/bin/",
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
err: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter unless failed on Exec[mkdir_autostart]: 
'[ -d  /home/pi/.config/autostart ]' is not qualified and no path was specified.
Please qualify the command or specify a path.
```

Also tried with onlyif statement, but that generated the same error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Added path (`path    => "/usr/local/bin/:/bin/",`) and now get:

```
err: /Stage[main]/auto::Sign/Exec[mkdir_autostart]: Could not evaluate: Could not find command '['
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the "file" type:

```
file { "/home/pi/.config/autostart":
   ensure => directory
}
```

But if for any reason, you want to keep your "exec" type, use `test -d /home/pi/.config/autostart`

Comment: Might be good to link to the [file -> ensure docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-ensure) and worth noting that this is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **unless** I'd suggest just adding a **-p** flag to mkdir:

```
exec { "mkdir_autostart":
  command => "mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/autostart",
  path    => "/usr/local/bin/:/bin/"
}
```

Or better yet just use Puppet's **file** resource type as mentioned above by @sebastien.prudhomme.