# puppet syntax error on line 41, col 55: `T'

Tags: syntax-error, puppet

I am seeing this error when running the puppet agent... I am not sure which file has this syntax error..

```
% sudo puppet agent --test --environment production --debug --trace
--snip--

debug: report supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer/fact_handler.rb:28:in `find_facts'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer/fact_handler.rb:33:in `facts_for_uploading'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/configurer.rb:144:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:43:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent/locker.rb:23:in `lock'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:43:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/sync.rb:230:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:43:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:95:in `with_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:41:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:172:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:172:in `controlled_run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/agent.rb:39:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/agent.rb:339:in `onetime'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application/agent.rb:313:in `run_command'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:309:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:416:in `hook'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:309:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:407:in `exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:309:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:69:in `execute'
/usr/bin/puppet:4
**err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: Could not retrieve local facts: syntax error on line 41, col 55: `T'**
```

On puppet master I commented out line 
    ARGV << "--debug"
in file
    /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/config.ru
and restarted apache.

and observed the following in puppet master...

```
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Routes Registered:
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Route /^\/v2\.0/
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Route /.*/
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Found YAML while processing request parameter ignore (value: <--- 
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]:   - ".svn"
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]:   - CVS
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]:   - ".git">)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Evaluating match for Route /^\/v2\.0/
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Did not match path ("/production/file_metadatas/plugins")
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Evaluating match for Route /.*/
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/vim/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/wget/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/denyhosts/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/fail2ban/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/rsyslog/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/sendmail/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/epel/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/java/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/my_fw/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/postfix/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/monitor/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/timezone/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/awscli/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ntp/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/modules/wordpress/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: No plugins found in subpath '/etc/puppet/modules/newrelic/lib' (file / directory does not exist)
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Feb 22 04:24:13 ci puppet-master[28349]: file_metadata supports formats: pson b64_zlib_yaml yaml raw
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Handling request: PUT /production/report/07.xxx.xxxx.com
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Routes Registered:
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Route /^\/v2\.0/
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Route /.*/
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Evaluating match for Route /^\/v2\.0/
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Did not match path ("/production/report/07.xxx.xxxx.com")
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Evaluating match for Route /.*/
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Received report to process from 07.xxx.xxxx.com
Feb 22 04:24:14 ci puppet-master[28349]: Processing report from 07.xxx.xxxx.com with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
```

I am not sure how to debug this.. Any pointers?

Comment: Does `facter -p` yield an error as well? Does `facter` without `-p`? - No need to inspect the master, this is almost certainly an agent side issue.

Comment: @FelixFrank I see the following deprecated warining message (other than that facter output looks allright) %facter
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.

Comment: Can you put the full output of `puppet agent --test --trace` somewhere and link here?

Comment: Sure, here :  https://gist.github.com/maaand/adbb3b3000aab542bdfe

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a directory exists in puppet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108694/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-puppet)